# Помогите понять почему два похожих метода работают по разному

Tags: java, рекурсия, структуры-данных, методы

Пишу библиотеку для обработки однонаправленного списка, для тестирования есть такой класс DDS:

```
public class Node {
public int value;
public Node next;

public Node (int value, Node next){
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
}
```

теперь собственно к методам, для начала нужно создать 2 основных, добавить элемент в начало списка и удалить 1-й элемент в начале списка, код вышел таким:

```
public static Node add (Node tail, int elem) {
    return (tail.next == null) ? tail.next = new Node(elem, null) : new Node(tail.value, add(tail.next, elem));
}

public static Node remove (Node tail) {
    return (tail.next == null) ? null : new Node(tail.value, remove(tail.next));
}
```

вся беда в том, что если сделать так:

```
    public static void classTest () {
    Node testNode = NodeCreateAndPrint.nodeGenRecBackwards(9);// метод для создания экземпляра Node рандомом с передачей количества элементов
    add(testNode, 123);
    System.out.println("Test Node after_ add an element is " + NodeCreateAndPrint.nodePrintRecBackwards(testNode));
    add(testNode, 555);
    System.out.println("Test Node after_ add an element is " + NodeCreateAndPrint.nodePrintRecBackwards(testNode));
    remove(testNode);
    System.out.println("Test Node after_ rem an element is " + NodeCreateAndPrint.nodePrintRecBackwards(testNode));
}
```

получается вот такой результат:

> Testing SingleLLUtils_2
>
> Test Node after_ add an element is 4-->2-->5-->3-->9-->9-->6-->1-->9-->7-->123-->null
>
> Test Node after_ add an element is 4-->2-->5-->3-->9-->9-->6-->1-->9-->7-->123-->555-->null
>
> Test Node after_ rem an element is 4-->2-->5-->3-->9-->9-->6-->1-->9-->7-->123-->555-->null
> Process finished with exit code 0

т.е. переданный экземпляр не изменяется, в случае удаления элемента, а вот в случае добавления, изменяется (чтоб ему). Хотя, если присвоить результат работы метода новой Node, то получу ожидаемый результат.

почему происходит так?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `add` неправильный.

Оба метода вроде бы создают модифицированную копию списка (и возвращают первый элемент этой копии), но `add` ошибочно цепляет новый элемент к последнему узлу оригинала. Если его поправить следующим образом:

```
public static Node add (Node tail, int elem) {
    return (tail == null) ? new Node(elem, null) : new Node(tail.value, add(tail.next, elem));
}
```

то методами можно будет пользоваться, как

```
    testNode = add(testNode, 555);
    System.out.println("Test Node after_ add an element is " + nodePrintRecBackwards(testNode));
    //Вывод: 1-->7-->3-->3-->2-->2-->7-->5-->8-->123-->555-->null

    Node testNode2 = remove(testNode);
    System.out.println("Test Node after_ rem an element is " + nodePrintRecBackwards(testNode));
    //Вывод: 1-->7-->3-->3-->2-->2-->7-->5-->8-->123-->555-->null
    System.out.println("Test Node2 after_ rem an element is " + nodePrintRecBackwards(testNode2));
    //Вывод: 1-->7-->3-->3-->2-->2-->7-->5-->8-->123-->null
```

Comment: Спасибо, с этим разобрался! Но вот пока правил код задумался вот над чем, а что если сделать оба метода void чтобы они модифицировали переданный список?! %) тогда выходит что add() будет выглядеть вот так:
`public static void add (Node tail, int elem) {
        if (tail.next == null)
            tail.next = new Node(elem, null);
        else add(tail.next, elem);
    }`
а вот как сделать так, чтобы в remove() обнулить предпоследний элемент? т. е. какое должно быть условие остановки?

Comment: @Bender по-моему, только через `tail.next.next == null`, т.к. нам как-то нужно будет править предпоследний элемент списка. И отдельно обработать случай, когда список состоит из одного элемента. Если делать через рекурсию, то нужен будет основной метод, который обрабатывает случай списка из одного узла, и если узлов больше, вызывает второй метод, который рекурсивно дойдет до конца списка.

Comment: Или сделать `remove` так, чтобы он возвращал переданный аргумент (`tail`), если `tail.next != null` или `null`. И для непоследнего узла делать `tail.next = remove(tail.next)`;

Answer (score 3):

У вас метод `remove` возвращает совсем другой экземпляр класса. А выводите вы первоначальный `testNode`.

Это два корня от разные цепочек, с пересекающимися ссылками. Делайте

```
testNode = remove(testNode);
```

и будет всё в порядке.

При добавлении нет такой проблемы, так как там изменяется ссылка в существующем объекте `tail.next = ...`, а в случае с удалением метод возвращает новый корень цепочки.